# If I block and then unblock someone, will I get their SMS sent while that person was blocked?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

While using an iPhone 5, iOS 9, if I block someone, wait some time, and then unblock that person, will I receive SMS messages sent to me while that person was blocked?

Answer (score 1):

No, the messages are blocked and they're not stored anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about the iphone but if i block someone on the google pixel phone and then unblock them, the sms text comes through eventually even if it was sent while blocked.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. This doesn't really help answering the question; you might be more interested in answering questions at our sister site [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).